# How to fast refresh materialized views in Oracle after exchange partition

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning, materialized-views

I created a materialized view on a table.

SRC_TBL ---> MV

Fast refreshed materialized view. It completed successfully.

Did exchange partition between materialized view and target table.

MV ---> TGT_TBL

It also completed successfully. After exchange partition when I try to fast refresh it is throwing:

```
[Error] Execution (58: 1): ORA-32320: REFRESH FAST of "MV" unsupported after container table PMOPs
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2994
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Appreciate your inputs.

Regards, 
Dex.

Answer (score 1):

From the Messages manual, or the

```
oerr ora 32320
```

command:

```
32320, 00000, "REFRESH FAST of \"%s\".\"%s\" unsupported after container table PMOPs"
// *Cause:  A Partition Maintenance Operation (PMOP) has been performed on the
//          materialized view, and no materialized view supports
//          fast refersh after container table PMOPs.
// *Action: Use REFRESH COMPLETE.  Note: you can determine why your
//          materialized view does not support fast refresh after PMOPs using
//          the DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW() API.
```

So basically, no fast refresh after doing partition maintenance.